# Aura set value taking too much time when record size is more then 1000

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components

I declered a Aura variable

```
<aura:attribute name="topAccountList" type="List[]" default="[]" />
```

and after calling Init method Apex response is is not taking time but Aura component.set taking too much time to set the data in Aura Attribute Define by me.
Here is flow

> 1. Aura Apex Call using Init ->    **5-10 Seconds**
> 2. Setting Data to Aura Attribute ->  **40-60 Seconds**

```
component.set("v.topAccountList", response.getReturnValue())
```

> 3. DOM Inseration and Iteration -> **20-30 Second**

So it is very slow. 
Please help me to reduce some seconds if possible.

Answer (score 3):

For this it is best to use pagination to avoid this entire list being returned.
(See snippet of best [practices](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2017/04/lightning-components-performance-best-practices.html#data_retrieval) below)

- When making a call to the server, limit the columns and rows of the result set:
  Only SELECT the columns you need.
- Set a LIMIT on the query and provide a paging mechanism if needed. Don’t return huge numbers of rows at once.

For more insight regarding the pagination, please check [here](http://www.sfdcmonkey.com/2017/01/26/display-record-with-pager-buttons-lightning-component/).

Hope this helps a bit!

Comment: I don't want to use any pagination as per requirements.

Comment: I'm afraid, if pagination is not an option, increasing performance will be hard. :(  Certainly if the system even grows larger.

Comment: This is working very fast in my Visual Force Page why this is slow in lightning ?

Comment: Lightning components are much heavier to run on client side - on slower laptops, lightning will be way slower compared to classic.